# Ordering frames (blocks) in a page for mobile devices (.NET)

Tags: c#, vb.net, algorithm

I'm writing an program that traces the contour of individual frames within an image. The tracing is complete and works very well.

Basically I start pixel 0,0 and loop though each row until I find a contour pixel, then using the Moore neighborhood algorithm, I trace out the block until I reach my initial starting point.

However, if anyone has looked at a bitmap up close, you would see that the pixels are not perfectly straight and it's possible for frame #2 or #3 to have a slightly higher starting Y coordinate. Thus I will need to allow for some tolerance on the Y axis.

In the perfect world. I could sort the frames via (y) and then by (x) in ascending order.

Getting to the point, If I have the following image loaded into a bitmap class, and lets say I already knew the top left X, top left Y, width, and height for each frame. How could I programmatically sort the frames correctly?

**Image:** (figure 12, image a)
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3629985/figure/F12/

Answer (score 1):

You can conceptually align the nearly aligned the frames like this:

1. Sort the frame locations by X
2. Set each frame location within a few X pixels of the previous frame's location to the previous frame's X value.
3. Do the same for Y.

Then you can order them normally.